# Make a ListBox not select the first item after setting ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I like to populate a `Listbox` with a `List<T>` as the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`. It seems like as soon as I set the `ItemsSource`, my event handler for `SelectionChanged` fires, and my first item in the list is selected. I'd like to start the list up with nothing selected by default, and not have to try to handle the event until the user actually clicks on a member of the list.

This is in a PopUp window, so each time the list appears, it should be set to 'nothing selected', i.e. `SelectedIndex == -1`.

I suppose I could remove the event handler in the code, populate the list, set it to -1, and then add the event handler again, but seems like a kind of messy way to do it.

Comment: Is your `ListBox.ItemsSource` set in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Psychic debugging, do you have `ListBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` set to `True` in the XAML?

Given:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="TestListBox"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

And:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TestListBox.SelectionChanged += TestListBox_SelectionChanged;
        this.TestListBox.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(10, 10).ToList();
    }

    void TestListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I receieve a `NotImplementException`, meaning `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` is a likely culprit.

We can test hypothesis this by removing this attribute or setting it to false, which will not throw an exception until the user clicks on an item.

Comment: Why does that mean IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem is the culprit? Do you not get the exception when it is set to False?

Comment: @Henk: Sorry, when `false` or `null` I do not receive the exception.

Comment: Removing IsSync'd seems to do the trick, thanks! Got rid of a bunch of "is initialized..." junk to boot. Ken

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to bind the list to a public property, with a separate property for the current item.

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Images}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}" />

private IndexedImage _currentItem;
public IndexedImage CurrentItem
{
    get { return _currentItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentItem == value) return;
        _currentItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
    }
}

    private ObservableCollection<IndexedImage> _images;
    public ObservableCollection<IndexedImage> Images
    {
        get { return _images ?? (_images = new ObservableCollection<IndexedImage>()); }
        set
        {
            if (_images == value) return;
            _images = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Images");
        }
    }
```

CurrentItem is then totally under your control. When you start it's null and it gets set when they click an item or you set it manually.